# Data is added to database but postman returns blank. What am I missing?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postman, knex.js

I am trying to prepare an api by doing postgreSQL operations with knex.

My data model function, which will save the data, works fine. On the Routers side, I do this successfully, but the postman returns me an empty object.

**Data Model**

```
function addArticle(newArticle) {
    return db("article")
        .insert(newArticle, "id")
        .then(([id]) => {
            return ("article").where({ id }).first();
        });
}
```

***Routers***

```
router.post('/addArticle',(req, res, next) => {
    const newArticle = req.body;

    Article.addArticle(newArticle)
        .then((article) =>{
            res.status(201).json(article)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            res.status(500).json({...err})
        })
});
```

***POSTMAN***
[image]

Comment: If you want to return the inserted document details including _id created in the db in response,thenTry insertOne() instead of insert() function in your Data model.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use .returning('*') instead of .then after inserting data?

Also, I believe inserting into database is an asynchronous command, but I don't see async being used anywhere.